# How to divide object into two objects and return the objects separately?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a function that loops through data and some status to the data, and the function returns an object at the end, now I want if the object has 'LB' status then divide it into two objects for L and For B

Here is what I have tried so far

```js
function addData() {
  const data = [{
      period: '2024-12-31T00:00:00.000Z',
      USD: 1000,
    },
    {
      period: '2024-12-31T00:00:00.000Z',
      USD: 800,
    },
    {
      period: '2024-12-31T00:00:00.000Z',
      USD: 1200,
    },
    // Add more data objects here...
  ];

  const fractionL = 0.2;
  const fractionB = 0.7;

  const r0Data = data.map((r0row) => {

    // Create the object with 'flex' property
    const object = { ...r0row,
      flex: createFlex(r0row)
    };

    // Check if the object's flex status includes 'LB'
    if (object.flex.includes('LB')) {
      // Calculate the new USD value based on the specified fractions
      const usdForL = fractionL * object.USD;
      const usdForB = fractionB * object.USD;

      // Create an object for 'L' with the same properties and the calculated USD for 'L'
      const objectForL = { ...object
      };
      objectForL.flex = objectForL.flex.map((status) => (status === 'LB' ? 'L' : status));
      objectForL.USD = usdForL;

      // Create an object for 'B' with the same properties and the calculated USD for 'B'
      const objectForB = { ...object
      };
      objectForB.flex = objectForB.flex.map((status) => (status === 'LB' ? 'B' : status));
      objectForB.USD = usdForB;

      // Check if usdForL is truthy, return its object; otherwise, return usdForB's object
      if (usdForL) {
        return objectForL;
      } else if (usdForB) {
        return objectForB;
      }
    }

    // Return the original object if it doesn't meet the condition
    console.log('object', object);
    return object;
  });
}

function createFlex(row) {
  // Code logic goes here to create flex status
  // For demonstration, let's assume it always returns ['LB', 'L', 'B']
  return ['LB', 'L', 'B'];
}

console.log(addData());
```

The object returned at the end should not be the object which has flex status.

Expected result;

If the object has status 'LB'  then divide it into  two parts.

For 'L';

```
  {
      flex: ['L', 'L", 'L']
      period: '2024-12-31T00:00:00.000Z',
      USD: XX,
  },
```

For B

```
  {
      flex: ['B', 'B', 'B']
      period: '2024-12-31T00:00:00.000Z',
      USD: XX,
  }
```

Comment: I don't think "Check if usdForL is truthy" is what you really want. `usdForL` is just `fractionL * object.USD` and doesn't depend on the status.

Comment: @Barmar thanks can you provide the solution will be much helpful

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. You say to divide it into two parts, but then you're only returning one of them, either `objectForL` or `objectForB`.

Comment: Where does `flex: ['L', 'L", 'L']` come from? When `createFlex()` return `['LB', 'L', 'B']`, `objectForL.flex.map` will return `['L', 'L', 'B']`

Comment: That is what I have tried, but it does not work as intended, I need both of them, but I am not able to solve the issue, I will be thankful if you know the solution

Comment: You need to use `return [objectForL, objectForB]` to return both of them. Then use `.flatmap` instead of `.map()` so it spreads these into separate elements of the result.

Comment: @Barmar the status does not matter cause your right , what I want is to be able to return both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the status includes `LB`, return both `objectForL` and `objectForB` in an array. Change `.map()` to `.flatMap()` to flatten this into separate array elements in the result.

```js
function addData() {
  const data = [{
      period: '2024-12-31T00:00:00.000Z',
      USD: 1000,
    },
    {
      period: '2024-12-31T00:00:00.000Z',
      USD: 800,
    },
    {
      period: '2024-12-31T00:00:00.000Z',
      USD: 1200,
    },
    // Add more data objects here...
  ];

  const fractionL = 0.2;
  const fractionB = 0.7;

  const r0Data = data.flatMap((r0row) => {

    // Create the object with 'flex' property
    const object = { ...r0row,
      flex: createFlex(r0row)
    };

    // Check if the object's flex status includes 'LB'
    if (object.flex.includes('LB')) {
      // Calculate the new USD value based on the specified fractions
      const usdForL = fractionL * object.USD;
      const usdForB = fractionB * object.USD;

      // Create an object for 'L' with the same properties and the calculated USD for 'L'
      const objectForL = { ...object
      };
      objectForL.flex = objectForL.flex.map((status) => (status === 'LB' ? 'L' : status));
      objectForL.USD = usdForL;

      // Create an object for 'B' with the same properties and the calculated USD for 'B'
      const objectForB = { ...object
      };
      objectForB.flex = objectForB.flex.map((status) => (status === 'LB' ? 'B' : status));
      objectForB.USD = usdForB;

      return [objectForL, objectForB];
    }

    // Return the original object if it doesn't meet the condition
    console.log('object', object);
    return object;
  });
  
  return r0Data;
}

function createFlex(row) {
  // Code logic goes here to create flex status
  // For demonstration, let's assume it always returns ['LB', 'L', 'B']
  return ['LB', 'L', 'B'];
}

console.log(addData());
```